# Why is the number missing?

Tags: pine-script

Why is the number missing?

```
//@version=4
study("我的编号指标", shorttitle='My bianhao', overlay=true)

y = 0

for a =0  to 100
  y := a + 1

  l = label.new(bar_index[y],na)

  label.set_text(l, text = tostring(y))
  label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
  label.set_style(l, label.style_none)
  label.set_textcolor(l, textcolor = color.white)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the garbage collection process in Pine.
By default, only the last 50 drawing objects are kept on the chart.
That limit can be increased up to a maximum of 500 by using the `max_labels_count` parameter in the `study()` function.

```
study("我的编号指标", shorttitle='My bianhao', overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)
```

You can read more about the garbage collection in the [User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html) under [Total number of drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings).